# Proof: Set of vectors is not a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am working through my textbook and am stuck on this example problem:

Prove that the set of vectors $S = \{(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \mid x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_{n-1} \geq x_n \}$ in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n \geq 2$ is not a subspace.

I easily prove the first subspace requirement that $\mathbb 0 \in S$ as $0 + 0 + \dots + 0 = 0$. However in trying to prove that $u + v \in S \mid u, v \in S$ is not true I am unable to proceed past:

$$u = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$$

$$v = (y_1, y_2, \dots, y_n)$$

$$u + v = (x_1 + y_1, \dots, x_n + y_n) = r$$

Test $r$ for membership in $S$:

$$(x_1 + y_1) + \dots + (x_{n-1} + y_{n-1}) \geq x_n + y_n$$

Re-arranging we get

$$ (x_1 + \dots + x_{n-1}) + (y_1 + \dots + y_{n-1}) \geq x_n + y_n$$

Now I can't substitute the corresponding sum of $x_i$ or $y_i$'s with $\geq x_n$ or $\geq y_n$ as that is nonsensical. However I can't figure out what to do next. I have tried coming up with a counter example but have been unsuccessful.

A hint on how to approach this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For disproving you just need to find two vector whose sum is not in the vector space!

Comment: @Learner I've tried to come up a few counter examples however they have a way of 'balancing out' so it condition still holds. For example $(1, 0, 1), (-1, -1, -2)$ and $(0, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1)$ but in the second example $(0, 0, 0, 1)$ isn't in $S$.

Comment: It is a (closed) half-space.

Comment: It is closed under addition, not scalar multiplication.

Comment: Ah I see, working through with @avid19's answer helped me see that. I'm glad they had this example in the textbook!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Let $\vec{v}=(1,0,\dots,0)$. This is clearly in $S$. Is $-\vec{v}$ also in $S$?

Comment: No because $-1 + 0 + ... 0 \ngeq 0$. Perhaps it is the case that $u + v \in S \space | \space u, v \in S$ is true but not $\alpha v \in S \space | \space a \in \mathbb R, v \in S$ so I got stuck trying to disprove the true second condition?